# function declaring column names

Tags: r, dataframe, recode

I have a function written in R. Basically I am applying a function to data frame column based on its values. Can anyone help me?.................................

```
asd <- data.frame(a = c("High Impact", "High Impact", "Medium Impact"),
                  b = c("High Impact", "No Impact", "High Impact"),
                  c = c("Low Impact", "No Impact", "Medium Impact"))

final_score <- function(q1,q2,q3){
  # ifelse(c == "A", "Low", "High")
  if (q1 == "Not Applicable") {
    q1_value = 0
  } else if (q1 == "No Impact") {
    q1_value = 0
  } else if (q1 == "Low Impact") {
    q1_value = 1
  } else if (q1 == "Medium Impact") {
    q1_value = 2
  } else if (q1 == "High Impact") {
    q1_value = 3
  }
  
  if (q2 == "Not Applicable") {
    q2_value = 0
  } else if (q2 == "No Impact") {
    q2_value = 0
  } else if (q2 == "Low Impact") {
    q2_value = 1
  } else if (q2 == "Medium Impact") {
    q2_value = 2
  } else if (q2 == "High Impact") {
    q2_value = 3
  }
  
  if (q3 == "Not Applicable") {
    q3_value = 0
  } else if (q3 == "No Impact") {
    q3_value = 0
  } else if (q3 == "Low Impact") {
    q3_value = 1
  } else if (q3 == "Medium Impact") {
    q3_value = 2
  } else if (q3 == "High Impact") {
    q3_value = 3
  }
  fs  = q1_value + q2_value + q3_value
  return(fs)
}

###Expected output
asd$new <- final_score(asd$a,asd$b,asd$c)
              a           b             c       new
1   High Impact High Impact    Low Impact       7
2   High Impact   No Impact     No Impact       3
3 Medium Impact High Impact Medium Impact       7
```

I have a function written in R. Basically I am applying a function to data frame column based on its values. Can anyone help me?.................................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `dplyr` you can use `case_when` and `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

asd %>%
  mutate(new = rowSums(across(.fns = ~case_when(. %in% c("Not Applicable", "No Impact") ~ 0, 
                                  . =="Low Impact" ~ 1, 
                                  . == "Medium Impact" ~ 2, 
                                  . == "High Impact" ~ 3))))

#              a           b             c new
#1   High Impact High Impact    Low Impact   7
#2   High Impact   No Impact     No Impact   3
#3 Medium Impact High Impact Medium Impact   7
```

Comment: I was writing exactly the same (10 minutes later). So great answer.

Comment: Hi, Suppose there is another column called "d" . In this case, how do we take only 3 columns. ````asd <- data.frame(a = c("Low Impact", "High Impact", "Medium Impact"),
                  b = c("High Impact", "No Impact", "High Impact"),
                  c = c("Low Impact", "No Impact", "Medium Impact"),
                  d = c(1,2,3))
````

Comment: In `across` you can do `across(a:c, ~case_when(.....))`

Answer (score 1):

When you find yourself copying your code over and over again, think whether a loop or a function are the better answers. This is a proposal to do the computation without additional packages. However, recoding can be done even more simple with suitable packages. The `recode` function in `car` is just one worhtwhile proposal out of many.

```
# Your example data
asd <- data.frame(a = c("High Impact", "High Impact", "Medium Impact"),
                  b = c("High Impact", "No Impact", "High Impact"),
                  c = c("Low Impact", "No Impact", "Medium Impact"))


# a small function for one value:
score <- function(value){
  if (value == "Not Applicable") return(0)
  if (value == "No Impact") return(0)
  if (value == "Low Impact") return(1)
  if (value == "Medium Impact") return(2)
  if (value == "High Impact") return(3)
  return(NA)
}

# apply that small function to each value in asd

apply(asd, 1:2, score)

# rowSums are the sums of the rows...

asd$new <- rowSums(apply(asd, 1:2, score))

print(asd)
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
asd$new <- rowSums(
  `dim<-`(
    as.integer(factor(
      as.matrix(asd),
      levels = c("Low Impact", "Medium Impact", "High Impact")
    )),
    dim(asd)
  ),
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

gives

```
> asd
              a           b             c new
1   High Impact High Impact    Low Impact   7
2   High Impact   No Impact     No Impact   3
3 Medium Impact High Impact Medium Impact   7
```

Comment: Converting to factor and using the numeric value would be a good alternative if it weren't for the two strings ("Not Applicable" and "No Impact") sharing the same value 0.

Comment: @crestor Yes, exactly.